# Cannot login to WP after force recovery

Tags: login

I recently had an issue on my locally placed site with Mamp. I resolved it through a force recovery with some tech help. The Mysql server came back on after doing the force recovery however now I am unable to login into my wordpress site. I believe it may be something to do with the myphp.admin but could be completely wrong. I'm in way over my head at this point so could use some help.

Comment: Looks like I may have figured this out by removing the force recovery from my.cnf and saving. I also went to myphp.admin and did arepair of all the tables. Not sure which was the reason to being able to login now. However with that said I am still getting this error on mysql: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have access to the WP database (via your hosting phpMyAdmin), and that you can't recover you login via the 'lost password' thing.

I also assume that you can access the pages of the site (the non-admin pages).

So, it would appear that you need to recreate your admin user in the WP database. This page (among others found via the googles) will help you recreate the admin user http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/333-add-admin-via-mysql .

If your user already exists in the database, then you may just need to reset the password, again through using phpMyAdmin through your hosting account.